# Suppress the list item marker for an <li> element

Tags: css

How can I suppress the list item marker for a list element using only css?

```
___° Elément n°1
___° Elément n°2
___° Elément n°3
```

html :

```
<ul>
<li>- Item 1</li>
<li>- Item 2</li>
<li>- Item 3</li>
<li>- Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Firefox complies, not IE ! please help.

Comment: Please note SO is an English language site

Comment: I want to delete my question because it has "-3" downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS**

```
li {
list-style-type: none;
list-style-image: url(data:0); // FOR IE
}
```

This works better for *Internet Explorer 11*:

```
li {
list-style-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7);
}
```